# Two different answers when they are mathematically the same..?

Tags: python-3.x, math, syntax, brackets

I've encountered a bug in my program which is performing the re-arrangement method to find roots of equations.

I've noticed that Python produces two different answers based on brackets.
For example

```
-4**(1/3) = -1.5874010519681994
-4.0**(1/3) = -1.5874010519681994
(-4)**(1/3) = (0.7937005259840999+1.3747296369986024j)
(-4.0)**(1/3) = (0.7937005259840999+1.3747296369986024j)
```

I've assigned -4.0 to a variable x and then assign x**(1/3) to y, however I get the complex number instead of the actual answer.

Why is this? Is there an easy way of preventing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things going on in your examples.

First, the brackets around the `-4` matters, since exponentiation is done before negation in the order of operations. Thus in your first two examples the power is done first, then the negative is taken of the result of the power. This is what you expected so you did not query this, but this did not take the cube root of `-4` but the negative of the cube root of `4`.

The second issue is that most floating-point arithmetic in Python is not exact. The result of `1/3` is not a fraction but a floating-point number. If you use the `as_integer_ratio` method on a variable storing the value of `1/3` you get the result

```
(6004799503160661, 18014398509481984)
```

showing that it is not actually 1 over 3. Therefore, taking something to the power of `1/3` is not the same as taking its cube root, since no such fraction is actually involved. Python interprets the exponent as a real value, not a rational value, and for negative numbers as the base the value of `x**y` is interpreted as `exp(y*ln(x))` as is done in mathematics. The logarithm of a negative real number is a complex number so the final result is also complex.

If you actually want the cube root of `-4`  you could just write your computation as in your first two examples. If you want to take roots of possibly-negative numbers in general you could write a routine, with the definition

```
def power_frac(base, numerator, denominator):
    """Return base**(numerator/denominator) where base is a
    floating-point number and both numerator and denominator are
    integers.
    """
```

This function would need to check for many cases, since (for example) an even root of a negative number is not real. But this could be done. I do not believe such a function is baked into Python. Remember, the exponent must be given as two integers (or a Fraction value) since Python cannot figure out the exact fraction that you mean when you calculate the exponent as a floating-point division.

If you just want a cube root of any real number, you could use

```
def cuberoot(x):
    return x**(1/3) if x >= 0 else -(-x)**(1/3)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a more detailed explanation than my own answer!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the rationality of `1/3`. The power function `x**y` is either only defined for positive `x` in the real numbers context or for all `x` using the formula you gave or an refinement thereof in a complex numbers context. The complex cube root is defined as the root with the smallest angle, the numerical result is not influenced by the difference of `1/3` and `0.3333...334`.

Comment: Real-valued exponentiation is often defined in this way: `x**(m/n)` is, for `x` real and `m` and `n` integers and `n` positive, the `n`th root of `x**m` if it exists--if more than one such root exists in the real numbers, choose the positive root. The question and my answer are based on this common definition.  Your definition also exists but is used for non-rational exponents. Exponentiation is one of the few real operations that depends on the type of its arguments. Do you deny that my definition is often used?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bug, it's an issue of operator precedence. If you check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), you'll see the minus operator `-` has lower precedence than the exponentiation operator `**`. Thus, your first expression is:

```
- (4 ** (1/3))
```

And the second one is:

```
(-4) ** (1/3)
```

which isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: Okay, but how would I work around this if x = -4.0 and then I do x**(1/3)

Comment: Shouldn't (-4) ** (1/3) return the same as the first equation, the calculator does

Comment: @SylentNyte: Your calculator (such as the TI-Nspire CX) almost certainly calculates `1/3` as a Rational type or somesuch. Python, like practically all computer languages, calculates `1/3` as a floating-point number, which is not the same thing (see my answer).

Comment: Are you only interested in cube roots specifically, or arbitrary powers? Integer only or rational as well? You'd probably have to write some special casing for this, since the built in `pow` function won't do what you want.

Comment: @tzaman, function was def f(x): return (3*x**2 - x + 4)**(1/3), so cube roots specifically, can be either integer or rational. I was thinking of trying to do a try/except control flow but I cant think of how to implement it right now, brains moved onto maths

Comment: @SylentNyte: For the cube root of `x` you could use `x**(1/3) if x >= 0 else -(-x)**(1/3)`. I'll add that to my answer.